# "Search" procedure in Sharepoint using Web Services

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I am making one module in my project to avail search in Sharepoint.

I am using web Services (C#).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that your module wants to access Sharepoint search via webservice..then if you want to call the exposed Sharepoint **Services** webservice, this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470518.aspx) will give you some background. For **MOSS 2007**, [this is the relative reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625950.aspx)